# Passing Image to Crystal report Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm struggling with passing image to crystal report.I'm using ZXing in converting BookId from MysqlDatabase to QR Code and put the QR Code to a Picture Box and pass to my parameter imageUrl the Picture Box.
Now i'm facing this error Value does not fall within the expected range.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEQUI.png)

> ```
>      private void QRPrintForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>          cry.Load(@"C:\Users\ivan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LibrarySystemWithMobile\LibrarySystemWithMobile\QRPrint.rpt");
>         ConnectionChecker();
> ```

```
        string query = "SELECT BookId FROM tblbooks WHERE BookId = 101 ";
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, cn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions();

        var qr = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter();
        qr.Options = options;
        qr.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        var result = new Bitmap(qr.Write(dt.Rows[0]["BookId"].ToString()));
        pictureBox1.Image = result;

         //byte[] img = (byte[]) imgs;
         //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);


        cry.SetParameterValue("imageUrl", pictureBox1.Image);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cry;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

    }
```

[Myrpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN4oU.png)

Answer (score -1):

In case you are willing to consider a simpler approach, you can achieve the same thing via a User Function Library. You can create your own or here's a [list of 3rd-party UFLs](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).

Here's a [description of the QR Code function in my CUT Light UFL](https://milletsoftware.com/CUT_Light_User_Manual/#uflBarcodeQR()%20or%20uflBBarcodeQR()). The function generates and returns the path to the QR Code image. In Crystal, you use it in the 'Graphic Location' expression for a picture object. It then replaces the picture with the QR Code image on the fly.

Comment: SO is for answering programming questions, not selling products.